# Moving Points with 1D Noise

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, noise, perlin-noise

I'd like to move points in X & Y with 1D Noise. To further clarify, I don't want each point to move by a unique random number, but rather a larger noise over the whole line with gradients moving the points. The  Noise would serve as a multiplier for a move amount and would be a value between -1 and 1. For example, if the Noise value was 0.8, it would multiply the X & Y of points by the amount.

How would I go about this?

This is what I have so far (the black line is the original line). I think it's wrong, because the frequency is 1 but there appears to be multiple waves in the noise.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import math
from enum import Enum

#PerlinNoise by alexandr-gnrk
class Interp(Enum):
    LINEAR = 1
    COSINE = 2
    CUBIC = 3

class PerlinNoise():
    def __init__(self, 
            seed, amplitude=1, frequency=1, 
            octaves=1, interp=Interp.COSINE, use_fade=False):
        self.seed = random.Random(seed).random()
        self.amplitude = amplitude
        self.frequency = frequency
        self.octaves = octaves
        self.interp = interp
        self.use_fade = use_fade

        self.mem_x = dict()


    def __noise(self, x):
        # made for improve performance
        if x not in self.mem_x:
            self.mem_x[x] = random.Random(self.seed + x).uniform(-1, 1)
        return self.mem_x[x]


    def __interpolated_noise(self, x):
        prev_x = int(x) # previous integer
        next_x = prev_x + 1 # next integer
        frac_x = x - prev_x # fractional of x

        if self.use_fade:
            frac_x = self.__fade(frac_x)

        # intepolate x
        if self.interp is Interp.LINEAR:
            res = self.__linear_interp(
                self.__noise(prev_x), 
                self.__noise(next_x),
                frac_x)
        elif self.interp is Interp.COSINE:
            res = self.__cosine_interp(
                self.__noise(prev_x), 
                self.__noise(next_x),
                frac_x)
        else:
            res = self.__cubic_interp(
                self.__noise(prev_x - 1), 
                self.__noise(prev_x), 
                self.__noise(next_x),
                self.__noise(next_x + 1),
                frac_x)

        return res


    def get(self, x):
        frequency = self.frequency
        amplitude = self.amplitude
        result = 0
        for _ in range(self.octaves):
            result += self.__interpolated_noise(x * frequency) * amplitude
            frequency *= 2
            amplitude /= 2

        return result


    def __linear_interp(self, a, b, x):
        return a + x * (b - a)


    def __cosine_interp(self, a, b, x):
        x2 = (1 - math.cos(x * math.pi)) / 2
        return a * (1 - x2) + b * x2


    def __cubic_interp(self, v0, v1, v2, v3, x):
        p = (v3 - v2) - (v0 - v1)
        q = (v0 - v1) - p
        r = v2 - v0
        s = v1
        return p * x**3 + q * x**2 + r * x + s


    def __fade(self, x):
        # useful only for linear interpolation
        return (6 * x**5) - (15 * x**4) + (10 * x**3)

x = np.linspace(10, 10, 20)
y = np.linspace(0, 10, 20)

seed = 10

gen_x = PerlinNoise(seed=seed, amplitude=5, frequency=1, octaves=1, interp=Interp.CUBIC, use_fade=True)
noise_x = np.array([gen_x.get(pos) for pos in y])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.set_aspect("equal")
ax.plot(x, y, linewidth=2, color="k")
ax.scatter(x, y, s=20, zorder=4, color="k")
ax.plot(x+noise_x, y, linewidth=2, color="blue")
ax.scatter(x+noise_x, y, s=80, zorder=4, color="red")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you want to multiply the coordinates, which is to say the same noise having more effect on a point further from the origin? I believe things would feel much more natural if your noise was a force and your points were springs with a certain stiffness.

Comment: @Guimoute Thank you for the message. So let's say a point is at 10,10. The 1D noise corresponding with the position on the line is a value of 0.5. The move amount is 20. It would move 10 units to 20,10. Does that make sense? The important thing is that this noise map is affecting points with a gradient so they are moving connected...like in a wave.

Comment: So you want to add a sine to your x coordinate. Why not just so that then?

Comment: @MadPhysicist that wouldn't be noise, right? Also, how could I make 1 octave the length of the line?

Comment: @Dr.Pontchartrain. The linear frequency is related to angular (which is the argument to the sinusoid) by a factor of 2*pi